# How to hide reCaptcha for the first time (first entry)

Tags: php, recaptcha

I noticed some websites have reCaptcha (no Captcha) but it doesn't show on the first use. Maybe if you use two or more times (the particular form, either login or contact form) the captcha appears.

Is there anyway to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Store the users data either via IP & DB, `$_SESSIONS` or Cookies (Not recommended). You could then have a count on the amount times the client has viewed the specific page.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my issue. Take a look at this: myaccount.payoneer.com there is no captcha but once you type a wrong password, ta da! the captcha shows up. I have seen the same thing with recaptcha. How do I achieve that?

Comment: I completely understand your question. With your example, if you type in a fake username and password into myaccount.payoneer.com, and then click login, a cookie is then stored in the browser which reference's the failed authentication. There must be a script on the back-end which is looking for that cookie and if found, will show the captcha. If you delete the cookies for the domain and refresh page, the captcha will be gone.

Comment: Using the methods I have advised in my original comment (Sessions & Cookies), attempt to emulate with your own code and post back if you have any issues.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I will play around and see how this will be and post the final result here.